# InvalidCastException when invoking hash function

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have added a hash function to my existing code (a basic login page), expecting a String in return. Here is the function:

```
Public Shared Function sha256_hash(value As [String]) As [String]
    Using hash As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
         Return [String].Join("", hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)).[Select](Function(item) item.ToString("x2")))
    End Using
End Function
```

When I try to log in I get the following excepton:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.Byte,System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'.

I tried searching for a solution but found nothing. I'm not experienced with vb.net so help is appreciated.

Edit: 
This function seems to work fine in localhost, but when published to the web server it crashes. Could it be a framework issue?

Comment: That code works for me. How are you calling this function?

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: [`String.Join<T>(string,IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) was a new overload added in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Try to add `.ToArray()` at the end of your `Select`, like this `[Select](Function(item) item.ToString("x2")).ToArray()`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right. Either you use this code in .NET 4.0+, or as Misery suggest, you have to change the code to `Return [String].Join("", hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)).[Select](Function(item) item.ToString("x2")).ToArray())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce your case using .NET 3.5, which as Damien_The_Unbeliever said, does not contains `String.Join<T>(string,IEnumerable<T>)`.
`String.Join` is expecting an array of `String`and `Select`does return an `IEnumerable(Of T)`

With that said, you need to change your code by the following

```
Public Shared Function sha256_hash(value As [String]) As [String]
     Using hash As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
        Return [String].Join("", hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)).[Select](Function(item) item.ToString("x2")).ToArray())
    End Using
End Function
```

---

To make it work in .NET 2.0 as you asked, you need to remove your `Select` statement since it was introduced in .NET 3.5, then instead of using `Select` you can simply do a foreach over the array returned by `.ComputeHash` as presented below.

```
Public Shared Function sha256_hash(value As [String]) As [String]
    Using hash As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
        Dim hashString = String.Empty
        Dim computedHash = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value))
        For Each item In computedHash
            hashString = String.Concat(hashString, item.ToString("x2"))
        Next
        Return hashString
    End Using
End Function
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Will the function work with framework 2? If not,  what can I change to make it work?